# Corda V4 template app crashes while running deployNodes

Tags: java, gradle, blockchain, corda

This is my error log

> > Task :deployNodes Bootstrapping local test network in D:\CordaV4\cordapp-template-java-release-V4\cordapp-template-java-release-V4\build\nodes Generating node directory for Notary Generating node directory for
> >     PartyA Generating node directory for PartyB Waiting for all nodes to
> >     generate their node-info files...
>
> Error while generating node info file D:\CordaV4\cordapp-template-java-release-V4\cordapp-template-java-release-V4\build\nodes\PartyB\logs
>   
>   CAPSULE EXCEPTION: Could not find Java installation for requested version [Min. Java version: 1.8.0 JavaVersion: null Min. update
>
> version: {1.8=171}] (JDK required: false). You can override the used
>   Java version with the -Dcapsule.java.home flag. (for stack trace, run
>   with -Dcapsule.log=verbose)
>
> Error while generating node info file D:\CordaV4\cordapp-template-java-release-V4\cordapp-template-java-release-V4\build\nodes\Notary\logs
>   
>   CAPSULE EXCEPTION: Could not find Java installation for requested version [Min. Java version: 1.8.0 JavaVersion: null Min. update
>
> version: {1.8=171}] (JDK required: false). You can override the used
>   Java version with the -Dcapsule.java.home flag. (for stack trace, run
>   with -Dcapsule.log=verbose)
>
> Error while generating node info file D:\CordaV4\cordapp-template-java-release-V4\cordapp-template-java-release-V4\build\nodes\PartyA\logs
>   
>   CAPSULE EXCEPTION: Could not find Java installation for requested version [Min. Java version: 1.8.0 JavaVersion: null Min. update
>
> version: {1.8=171}] (JDK required: false). You can override the used
>   Java version with the -Dcapsule.java.home flag. (for stack trace, run
>   with -Dcapsule.log=verbose)
>
> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> - What went wrong: Execution failed for task ':deployNodes'.
>
>   > Error while generating node info file. Please check the logs in D:\CordaV4\cordapp-template-java-release-V4\cordapp-template-java-release-V4\build\nodes\PartyB\logs.
> - Try: Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
> - Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
>
> BUILD FAILED in 27s 12 actionable tasks: 10 executed, 2 up-to-date

I tried putting the java path in the gradle file as well as the gradle properties file but still no result.

Answer (score 0):

For Corda V4, we need to install Java version 8u171 or higher.

Please add "Java" to the PATH environment variable by following the instructions at -

"https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/webnotes/install/windows/jdk-installation-windows.html#path"

Please refer the following link for setting up the environment -

"https://docs.corda.net/releases/release-V4.0/getting-set-up.html"